# Shadow effect on image loaded in imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, shadow

in my app I need to add shadow effect on image loaded in imageview(from url). 
Below are the things I have tried yet:-

Code for xml :-

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_effect_imageview"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="0.2dp"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0" 
            android:shadowRadius="0.7"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Code for shadow_effect_imageview:-

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="#CCCCCC"
        android:endColor="#595959"
        android:angle="270"
        >
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

But using these it shows shadow effect on imageview as lazy loading but what I want is to keep same effect on image even after loading image.
Will anyone please suggest me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is good for you http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki)

Animation are supported in this library.
Check [example](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/09/android-image-loading-libraries-picasso.html)

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);

Glide.with(this).load(URL).animate(anim).into(imageView);
```